# iPhone UIButton Tap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to make a button that response to single and double tap. I am trying to do this using myAction method. The problem is that first time when I press the button the method myAction isn't called.

Can somebody tell why this happening and how can I fix that?

```
-(IBAction)myButton:(id)sender{
   UIButton *theButton = (UIButton *)sender;
   [theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
}

- (void)myAction:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   NSLog(@"Touch events goes here");
}
```

Thank you,

I. Vasilev

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you link the event with myButton:sender

So, it simply means:

> ```
> When tap at myButton, 
>   register `myAction` to the button's event handler.
> ```

You can fix this by call myAction directly or, just relink the event to myAction: instead.

Comment: Just to clarify what Bird said, it appears that you've configured the button in Interface Builder to send the -myButton: action message whenever it's clicked. Why not just configure it to send the -myAction: message instead?

Comment: Hello Bird,
I've fixed the problem calling my Action directly.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

You should define the functions in your header file("MyViewController.h, for example").

```
@interface bla bla {

}

- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender;
- (void)myAction:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event;

@end
```

Comment: I have myButton defined, but I think I forgot to define myAction. Do you think that this me be the problem? 
The method myAction log the result, on my 2nd, 3rd etc. tap.

Comment: I should do it just in case. If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know.